# Scala/Akka/Guice dynamically injecting child actors

Tags: scala, akka, guice

I would like to be able to create multiple instances of the same parent actor, but with different child actors.  I assume this has to be possible with Guice, but I haven't found the solution.

Here is what I have in mind ~

**Controller:**

```
class Application @Inject()(@Named(ParentActor.parentActor1) parentActor1: ActorRef,
                        @Named(ParentActor.parentActor2) parentActor2: ActorRef)
  extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    parentActor1 ! "Message"
    parentActor2 ! "Message"
    Ok()
  }
}
```

**Parent Actor:**

```
object ParentActor {
  final val parentActor1 = "parentActor1"
  final val parentActor2 = "parentActor2"
}

class ParentActor @Inject() (childActor: ActorRef) extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case "Message" =>
      println(s"ParentActor ${self.path} received message...")
      childActor ! "Message"
  }
}
```

**Child Actor A:**

```
class ChildActorA extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case "Message" =>
      println("ChildActorA received message...")
  }
}
```

**Child Actor B:**

```
class ChildActorB extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case "Message" =>
      println("ChildActorB received message...")
  }
}
```

**Module:**

```
class Modules extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {

  override def configure() = {
    bindActor[ParentActor](ParentActor.parentActor1)
    bindActor[ParentActor](ParentActor.parentActor2)
  }
}
```

What if I wanted "parentActor1" to have have its "childActor" ref point to an instance of ChildActorA and "parentActor2" to have its "childActor" ref point to an instance of ChildActorB?  Is this possible to achieve with Guice?

Comment: Did you try to inject `Props` instead of `ActorRef`?

Comment: @Sergey could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I guess one alternative solution would be to use what I think is called "introduction", whereby the ParentActor would be "introduced" to the appropriate child actor.  For instance, my controller would send a message to ParentActor like "Message(childActor)" where "childActor" is an ActorRef to the appropriate child actor (either ChildActorA or ChildActorB).

Answer (score 3):

I'm using some code based on https://github.com/rocketraman/activator-akka-scala-guice to accomplish something similar

I'm not using Play, so I have to initialize Guice and bootstrap the actor system

```
import akka.actor._
import javax.inject.{Inject, Provider, Singleton}
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import net.codingwell.scalaguice.InjectorExtensions._
import com.google.inject.Guice
import com.google.inject.Injector
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

object Bootstrap extends App {

  val injector = Guice.createInjector(
    new AkkaModule(),
    new ServiceModule()
  )

  implicit val system = injector.instance[ActorSystem]

  val parentActor1 = system.actorOf(ParentActor.props(ChildActorA.name))
  val parentActor2 = system.actorOf(ParentActor.props(ChildActorB.name))


  parentActor1 ! "Message"
  parentActor2 ! "Message"

  system.terminate()

  Await.result(system.whenTerminated, Duration.Inf)  
}
```

To initialize Guice there are two classes/objects:

One to initialize the extension and inject the actor system where required

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import AkkaModule.ActorSystemProvider
import com.google.inject.{AbstractModule, Injector, Provider}
import com.typesafe.config.Config
import net.codingwell.scalaguice.ScalaModule
import javax.inject.Inject

object AkkaModule {

  class ActorSystemProvider @Inject() (val injector: Injector) extends Provider[ActorSystem] {

    override def get() = {

      val system = ActorSystem("actor-system")

      GuiceAkkaExtension(system).initialize(injector)

      system
    }
  }
}

class AkkaModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {

  override def configure() {
    bind[ActorSystem].toProvider[ActorSystemProvider].asEagerSingleton()
  }

}
```

another one to create the providers for the children

```
import javax.inject.Inject

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem}
import com.google.inject.name.{Named, Names}
import com.google.inject.{AbstractModule, Provides, Singleton}
import net.codingwell.scalaguice.ScalaModule

class ServiceModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule with GuiceAkkaActorRefProvider {

  override def configure() {
    bind[Actor].annotatedWith(Names.named(ChildActorA.name)).to[ChildActorA]
    bind[Actor].annotatedWith(Names.named(ChildActorB.name)).to[ChildActorB]
  }

  @Provides
  @Named(ChildActorA.name)
  def provideChildActorARef(@Inject() system: ActorSystem): ActorRef = provideActorRef(system, ChildActorA.name)

  @Provides
  @Named(ChildActorB.name)
  def provideChildActorBRef(@Inject() system: ActorSystem): ActorRef = provideActorRef(system, ChildActorB.name)

}
```

The extension

```
import akka.actor._
import com.google.inject.Injector

class GuiceAkkaExtensionImpl extends Extension {

  private var injector: Injector = _

  def initialize(injector: Injector) {
    this.injector = injector
  }

  def props(actorName: String) = Props(classOf[GuiceActorProducer], injector, actorName)

}

object GuiceAkkaExtension extends ExtensionId[GuiceAkkaExtensionImpl] with ExtensionIdProvider {

  override def lookup() = GuiceAkkaExtension

  override def createExtension(system: ExtendedActorSystem) = new GuiceAkkaExtensionImpl

  override def get(system: ActorSystem): GuiceAkkaExtensionImpl = super.get(system)

}

trait NamedActor {
  def name: String
}

trait GuiceAkkaActorRefProvider {

  def propsFor(system: ActorSystem, name: String) = GuiceAkkaExtension(system).props(name)

  def provideActorRef(system: ActorSystem, name: String): ActorRef = system.actorOf(propsFor(system, name))

}
```

producer

```
import akka.actor.{IndirectActorProducer, Actor}
import com.google.inject.name.Names
import com.google.inject.{Key, Injector}

class GuiceActorProducer(val injector: Injector, val actorName: String) extends IndirectActorProducer {

  override def actorClass = classOf[Actor]

  override def produce() = injector.getBinding(Key.get(classOf[Actor], Names.named(actorName))).getProvider.get()

}
```

and your actors

```
import javax.inject.Inject
import akka.actor._


object ParentActor {

  def props(childName: String)(implicit @Inject() system: ActorSystem) = Props(classOf[ParentActor],system.actorOf(GuiceAkkaExtension(system).props(childName)))

}

class ParentActor (childActor: ActorRef) extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case "Message" =>
      println(s"ParentActor ${self.path} received message...")
      childActor ! "Message"
  }
}

object ChildActorA extends NamedActor{

  override final val name = "ChildActorA"
  def props() = Props(classOf[ChildActorA])

}

class ChildActorA extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case "Message" =>
      println("ChildActorA received message...")
  }
}

object ChildActorB extends NamedActor{

  override final val name = "ChildActorB"
  def props() = Props(classOf[ChildActorB])

}


class ChildActorB extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case "Message" =>
      println("ChildActorB received message...")
  }
}
```

the output from sbt

```
> run
[info] Running Bootstrap 
ParentActor akka://actor-system/user/$b received message...
ParentActor akka://actor-system/user/$d received message...
ChildActorB received message...
ChildActorA received message...
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Jun 14, 2016 1:23:59 AM
```

You have to explicitly name the children,

It's not the purest or most elegant answer, and I'm sure the code can be optimized, but it allows you to create instances of the same parent with different children.

I'm thinking that you can also use BindingAnnotations

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer!  Let me test this out when I get a free moment and I will get back to you...